# Image object as a property of player in HTML5 game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm creating a HTML5 canvas game and have made the image objects part of the players / Enemy constructors. I then call the draw function, passing the player object.
Are there any disadvantages to doing this? I'm also running a check to ensure images have downloaded before calling the game loop.

In most cases the image objects are created with the games global variables.

```
function Player() {
  this.width = 120;
  this.height = 129;
  this.img = new Image();   // image object 
  this.img.src = 'img/player';
 }

function Enemy() {
  this.width = 120;
  this.height = 129;
  this.img = new Image(); // image object 
  this.img.src = 'img/enemy';
 }
```

Many thanks

Comment: _"Are there any disadvantages to doing this?"_ Is __primarily opinion-based__

Comment: Not really, it is certainly possible to objectively list advantages and disadvantages of programming patterns given OPs requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Disadvantages: Each game object holds its own DOM Image element. If two or more enemies look the same (have the same image source), you would optimally only instantiate one image with that source.

Therefore I recommend to make that image part of the game object's prototype, so it is shared among all instances.

A more advanced technique would be to use a resource manager which is responsible for loading and keeping track of images and can thus prevent duplicates over different prototypes, too.

A resource manager would easily allow you to combine multiple images/textures into a larger file and load them at once. See e. g. [What is the best practice for loading multiple textures in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323620/what-is-the-best-practice-for-loading-multiple-textures-in-three-js)